# Where to apply the parent theme class when using :host-context(.theme_name) in Angular2?

Tags: css, angular, themes

I'm building a themed Angular2 app. I have loads of nested components and I would like to change the theme for the whole app by changing one parent class. Let's say one theme is called "theme1". When I apply this to a very parent html-tag, all the nested child components will then switch style by using :host-context, like this:

```
:host-context(.theme1) .title-toc {
    font-family: "bookmania";
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20pt;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #a5a5a5;
}
```

However, where to put this class="theme1"? When I put it to `<body>`, it worked so the code itself works, but I need to change the theme dynamically so it has to be inside some Angular component instead where I can use `[ngClass]`. For example inside AppComponent. But when I put it inside app.component (for example router-outlet or any other wrapping tag that should wrap my whole app), it didn't work anymore.

Do I have to make it deep with ::ng-deep somehow or what could be wrong?

Comment: What about putting that on the root component? You can set that via `@HostBinding('attr.class') mainClass = 'theme1';`

Comment: This works! So cool. Thanks! If you add this as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to your root component element's `class` attribute like this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  @HostBinding('attr.class') mainClass = 'theme1';

  changeTheme(theme) {
    this.mainClass = theme;
  }

}
```

Comment: Btw, is it possible to apply the class WHILE preserving the possible classes the main class already has? It seems that this technique overwrites the current classes (like col-classes when using Bootstrap)

Comment: Got it myself, it seems I can do like this:
@HostBinding('attr.' + myClassNameInVariable) true;

Comment: You could also bind via separate bool property for each theme: `@HostBinding('class.theme1') theme1 = true;`

Comment: Oh, hmm, I'm not sure if my way works after all. In your way - what if the class name "theme1" is in a variable, how would I do then?

Comment: I do not think you can do that.

Comment: But you could go the original approach I proposed in my answer and handle that yourself (split the string to array of classes, check if it contains something before adding, etc...)

Comment: This seemed to work when binding with a classname that is in a variable: @HostBinding('class.' + my_classname_variable) value = true;

It seems that the 'value'-variable name doesn't have to refer to a class name - it can be anything so it doesn't need to be the same name as in the class. So I can use the variable to build the 'class.classname'-string and it works well. Like you suggested.

Comment: After experimenting, I can set the HostBinding class if I use a variable I import from elsewhere by import (for example import { MySettings } from 'settings', but I can't set the class from a variable that I have in the current component (it says the variable is undefined, it seems HostBinding is done before the constructor).

You mentioned trying the original approach - how do you mean? I can't figure out a way to read the current classes. Binding to 'class' lets me set them, but the variable is "undefined" if I print it to console - I can only set new ones into it.

Answer (score 0):

:host-context() sees the classes applied on the document **body**. You can set the class of body with JavaScript after the application has loaded, like this:

```
var myclass = "my-theme-name";
document.querySelector('body').classList.add(myclass);
```

This way you can load the theme name even from server and then apply it to the body from any Angular2 component via JS:

```
:host-context(.my-theme-name) .my-theme-specific-style
```